# Python Pandas create dummy variables with values other than 1 or 0?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have created dummy variables in pandas using the get_dummies() function. I want to modify the results to use another metric rather than just the binary yes/no that get_dummies creates.

How the dummy variable dataframe looks now:

```
    VALUE   DUMMY 1 DUMMY 2 DUMMY 3
    10.00   0       0       1
    30.00   0       1       0
    50.00   0       0       0
    15.00   1       0       0
    30.00   0       0       0
```

What I am trying to achieve:

```
   VALUE    DUMMY 1 DUMMY 2 DUMMY 3
    10.00   0       0       10
    30.00   0       30      0
    50.00   0       0       0
    15.00   15      0       0
    30.00   0       0       0
```

The way I have thought about doing this is:

```
    np.where(df.COLUMN ==1, df.REPLACEMENT_VALUE, 0)
```

However this only works on one column. If I try:

```
    np.where(df[:,1:5] ==1, df.REPLACEMENT_VALUE, 0)
```

It doesn't work because the shape of the frame to the series is inconsistent. Duplicating the series REPLACEMENT_VALUE might be an option so the frames are the same size. I am not sure if this is the best way though. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you just do something like `df['DUMMY 1'] *= df.VALUE`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `mul` method:

```
In [75]: df
Out[75]: 
   VALUE  DUMMY 1  DUMMY 2  DUMMY 3
0     10        0        0        1
1     30        0        1        0
2     50        0        0        0
3     15        1        0        0
4     30        0        0        0

[5 rows x 4 columns]

In [76]: df.loc[:, 'DUMMY 1':'DUMMY 3'].mul(df['VALUE'], axis=0)
Out[76]: 
   DUMMY 1  DUMMY 2  DUMMY 3
0        0        0       10
1        0       30        0
2        0        0        0
3       15        0        0
4        0        0        0

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Can also use df.filter(regex='DUMMY') rather than loc :)